# How to convert KNN Scikit-learn Model in python to tensorflow lite model?

Tags: python, tensorflow-lite, knn

This is my sample code for a KNN classifier with accuracy over 90%,

```
sc_X = StandardScaler()

 X_train = sc_X.fit_transform(X_train)

 X_test = sc_X.transform(X_test)

 k=10
 classifier=KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k)

 classifier.fit(X_train,y_train)

 y_pred=classifier.predict(X_test)

 acc=accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)

print("For K=",k,"-->Accuracy is:",acc) 


Am trying to convert the above listed model to a tensor flow lite model using this,

converter = lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(classifier)

tfmodel = converter.convert()

open('trained_model.tflite', 'wb').write(tfmodel)
```

But i am getting this error,

'KNeighborsClassifier' object has no attribute 'call'

Is there anyway to convert a trained knn model in python to tflite model?

Comment: You can't convert a sklearn model to tensorflow or save it as a keras model.

Comment: Is there any simple implementation of knn model in keras or any other type, which is also accepted by tensor flow conversion, am trying to deploy a model in an android app (using android studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `KNeighborsClassifier` is part of the sklearn library. `lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model` supports keras models, not sklearn models. You need to build & train a [Keras classifier](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification).

Comment: Is there a simple implementation in keras for classification models just like with sklearn libraries ?

Comment: Yup, the codelab I linked in the answer shows a simple Keras classifier training, and you can customize it from there :-)